# d3js + circle not included in my chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have a problem with d3js. I create an SVG with a width and a heigth, but i only have 1 circle how is visible the ohter are outside the height of the SVG. i don't know why.

Here the code :

```
var data = [
  {age : 10 , score : 2000},
  {age: 50 , score : 500},
  {age: 20 , score : 500},
  {age: 45 , score : 100},
  {age: 32 , score : 1000},
  {age: 89 , score : 552},
];


var margin = {top : 40 , right:40, bottom:40, left:40},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append('g')
  .attr("transform", 
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.age; }))
.range([0, width ])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.score; })])
.range([height, 0 ])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
.scale(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
.scale(y);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
.call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
.enter().append('circle')
  .attr("cx", function(d){return d.age})
  .attr("cy", function(d){return d.score})
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("r",3)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the scales, which you have defined.

```
svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
.enter().append('circle')
  .attr("cx", function(d){return x(d.age)})
  .attr("cy", function(d){return y(d.score)})
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("r",3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways:

1- using the one Sina has explained, which is the quickest to do.

2- Doing a little bit of computation, which is a bit helpful to understand how d3 scaling works.

Here is the second approach:

```
var data = [{
    age: 10,
    score: 2000
  },
  {
    age: 50,
    score: 500
  },
  {
    age: 20,
    score: 500
  },
  {
    age: 45,
    score: 100
  },
  {
    age: 32,
    score: 1000
  },
  {
    age: 89,
    score: 552
  },
];


var margin = {
    top: 40,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append('g')
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.age;
  })])
  .range([0, width])

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.score;
  })])
  .range([height, 0])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
  .scale(x);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
  .scale(y);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append('g')
  .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll(".dot")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return (width / d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.age;
    })) * d.age
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return (height / d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.score;
    })) * Math.abs(d.score - d3.max(data, function(d) {
      return d.score;
    }))
  })
  .attr("fill", "blue")
  .attr("r", 3)
```